# Full template instantiation forced in C++ template inheritance?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, instantiation

We all know a C++ class template does not generate member functions that are not used, as illustrated below:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    public:
    void WrongFunction(T t);
    void RightFunction(T t);
};

template<typename T>
void A<T>::WrongFunction(T t)
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    auto a = "abc" - v;
}

template<typename T>
void A<T>::RightFunction(T t)
{
    std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    a.RightFunction(2);
    //a.WrongFunction(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Since the WrongFunction is not called in main, there's no actual code generated for it and therefore no compilation error occurs.

Now, let's introduce an abstract base class that defines the interface for class A(basically, template inheritance):

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void RightFunction(T t) = 0;
    virtual void WrongFunction(T t) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class A : Base<T>
{
    public:
    void WrongFunction(T t) override;
    void RightFunction(T t) override;
};

template<typename T>
void A<T>::WrongFunction(T t)
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    auto a = "abc" - v;
}

template<typename T>
void A<T>::RightFunction(T t)
{
    std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    a.RightFunction(2);
    //a.WrongFunction(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Suddenly, the compiler refuses to work:

> prog.cc: In instantiation of 'void A::WrongFunction(T) [with T =
>   int]': prog.cc:39:1:   required from here prog.cc:24:20: error: no
>   match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'const char [4]' and
>   'std::vector >')
>        auto a = "abc" - v;

My understanding of the work flow is, in main, I say create an instance of A. Fine, the compiler then finds the template declaration for A(note that A is not a class; `A<SomeType>` is.). Wow, it depends on `Base<int>`. Fine, the compiler then finds the template declaration for Base, plugs int into the position held by T - now we have the declaration for the class `Base<int>`, but no definition is generated - after all, we did not provide a template for definition generation for `Base<SomeType>`, and no one has ever created any instance of `Base<int>` or has called a function on the instance. That's fine. Then the compiler extends the declaration of `Base<int>` and generates the declaration of `A<int>`. Wait, on the next line, RightFunction is called. So the compiler finds the template definition for RightFunction for A and plugs in the specific type int and generates the member function definition for A.

**Since WrongFunction is never called(no specialization involved either; no explicit instantiation either), the compiler shouldn't even try to generate the code for `A<int>`::WrongFunction --- my question is, what the heck is going on?**

Compiler: gcc 4.9.2

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you need to have an address that you can put into the virtual table. So yeah, I'm way to busy to look it up in the standard, but the methods must be compiled to have an address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From N3337, *§14.7.1/10 [temp.inst]*

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class, or a static data member of a class template that does not require instantiation. **It is unspecified whether or not an implementation implicitly instantiates a virtual member function of a class template if the virtual member function would not otherwise be instantiated.** ...

So it's legal for an implementation to instantiate the virtual member function even though you never call it.

In practice, this is likely to always be the case because when instantiating a class template the compiler also needs to instantiate the vtable for that class which must be filled with the addresses of virtual member functions.

Comment: But a smart compiler could do whole program optimization and prove that the virtual function was never called, and decide not to create it.  I am unaware of a compiler that does this.

Comment: @Yakk Hey Yakk nice to see you again :) But I don't think it's feasible. virtual table lookup is a run time behavior. The compiler generally has no idea which function actually gets called from the code `basePtr->SomeFunction();`. I think that's probably why(simply too difficult to get it right) the C++ standard does not formally forbid the implicit instantiation even though the behavior is different from the case without inheritance.

Comment: @h9uest If nobody access the vtable entry in the entire program, and it isn't exported, then under as-if it can be eliminated.  And under the standard, it is not MANDATED that the virtual function exist merely because it is virtual.  This requires the compiler analyze the entire program for vtable access before it instantiates the function, which no compiler that I am aware of does, but should be perfectly legal.

Comment: @Yakk Of course, a smart compiler could do that, but it seems it would cause more problems than it solves. A not-so-smart compiler wouldn't be able to compile your code anymore, and even the smart compiler might, at some point, find itself unable to perform that analysis due to some construct you introduced, causing your code to stop compiling.